# How to notify Websockets from Redis messages with sinatra, sinatra-websocket and redis-rb?

Tags: redis, sinatra

I have this https://gist.github.com/ohcibi/5418898 Gist which is basically just the example from the sinatra-websocket github page and a bit of Redis code pasted in. The part

```ruby
settings.redis.subscribe 'foobar' do |on|
  on.message do |channel, message|
    settings.sockets.each do |s|
      s.send message
    end
  end
end
```

is blocking the Sinatra app to boot properly aus `subscribe` is blocking. I made small success by putting the subscription inside the `ws.onopen` handler but this would override the subscription for every new websocket (i.e. only the newest websocket will receive the message).

How to do it to be able to notify all connected sockets when a new redis message is incoming?

Answer (score 0):

I was successful by putting it in another Thread and using Thread locals for the sockets:

```ruby
set(:watcher, Thread.new do
  redis = Redis.new
  Thread.current['sockets'] = []

  redis.subscribe 'foobar' do |on|
    on.message do |channel, message|
      Thread.current['sockets'].each do |s|
        s.send message
      end
    end
  end
end)
```

I then do

```ruby
settings.watcher['sockets'] << ws
```

instead of

```ruby
settings.sockets << ws
```

and

```ruby
settings.redis.publish 'foobar', msg
```

to notify the sockets via the redis watcher.

See the updated gist: https://gist.github.com/ohcibi/5418898